# Как вывести введённую строку задом наперёд?

Tags: java, массивы, строки, for

Я преобразую строку в массив символов с помощью функции `toCharArray()`.

Далее продвигаюсь от конца массива к началу, конец массива нахожу с помощью `length`. Но почему-то код не работает и выдаёт ошибку, что индекс `i` за пределами границ.

Мой код:

```java
package ua.com.sololearn;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SoloLearnTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String words = scan.nextLine();
        char[] arr = words.toCharArray();

        for (int i = arr.length; i > 0; i--) {          
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
Hello there
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11
    at ua.com.sololearn.SoloLearnTest.main(SoloLearnTest.java:11)
    
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это потому, что массивы индексируются с `0`. Вы же берете длину массива (например `7`) и в первой итерации вы подставляете `7`-ку в качестве индекса, а такого элемента не существует, крайний индекс в вашем массиве будет `6`. Вот вы и ловите данную ошибку.

```
 for(int i = arr.length-1;i>=0;i--){          
       System.out.println(arr[i]);           
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно без циклов вообще:

StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(input).reverse();